# How do I exit a NetBeans Platform GUI application?

Tags: java, netbeans

How to I programmatically properly exit a NetBeans Platform application when the TopComponent has been declared in an XML file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "when the TopComponent has been declared in an XML file" but the answer for how to properly exit a NetBeans Platform application is:

```
LifecycleManager.getDefault().exit();
```

What you definitely should **not** do is the normal Java way:   `System.exit();`.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks a bunch. :-) I couldn't find out how the main window was starting up. Turns out NetBeans magic was starting it. I was looking so I could see how it got shut down when someone clicked the X, but didn't find it.

Comment: How we force to quite? Now when this code is executed a message is shown to user to confirm exit. Is it possible force to quite without change normal process?